# Stop ThreadPoolTaskExecutor on Exception

Tags: java, multithreading, spring

Is it possible to stop a `org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` when a non catched Exception is thrown, and how to do that ?

For example, when `MyCustomException` is thrown, I would like to stop the thread and catch the Exception in the main thread :

```
taskExecutor.execute(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            int i = 1/0;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new MyCustomException(e);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Why would you want to stop the executor? That would make everything that uses that executor stop or might even break your application.

Comment: You could use a callback. Give the Runnable a reference to the desired handler and call a method on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using anonymous inner classes, this should suffice:

```
taskExecutor.execute(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            int i = 1/0;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            onExceptionInTask( new MyCustomException(e) ); // <== Inform main.
        }
    }
});
```

which is a call to a method in the "main" class:

```
protected void onExceptionInTask( MyCustomException e ){
    // do your thing like stop all tasks ... 
}
```